# How to differentiate different sources in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to add something to the URL so Google analytics has statistics on where it came from. Right now I have "https://my-site.com" link everywhere. What if I put some path parameters to the URLs like "https://my-site.com?source=stack-overflow" or "https://my-site.com?source=catalogue".
My question is: what can I attach to the URL so Google analytics knows what source requests came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use UTM parameters: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en